# Efficient get product url from id

Tags: product, magento-1, url, performance, best-practice

What is the most efficient way of getting a product url given just it's ID? In a few places in our code we have things such as `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id)->getProductUrl()` in order to get the URL of the product, given the amount of events etc associated with a product this seems rather wasteful, is there a simpler method? The ability to also specify a category id would be nice.

Additionally, is there an efficient method for doing the same thing for a single attribute for a product such as name?

Comment: did your question get solved here? Did you need more help on this question? If so let us know what needs to be done to help you find a solution.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Interesting to know if we can get the product URL without loading whole product. Sorry to answer your additional question and not the main question, as I am also not sure if we can get it :)

For getting a single attribute without loading whole product, you can use `getAttributeRawValue()` if you are using Magento CE version 1.6+

`Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'attribute_code', $storeId);`

As per @philwinkle's comment below, here is more optimized code:

```
Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product')
  ->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'attribute_code', Mage::app()->getStore());
```

UPDATE: Get product URL by ID without loading whole product:

```
Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product')
  ->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'url_key', Mage::app()->getStore());
```

Comment: Wowzers. Didn't know about that one! Everybody upvote this answer. 

If you really want to up the ante, you can reuse an existing catalog/product resource model (instead of instantiating a new one) by calling `getResourceSingleton` instead. $storeId doesn't have to be an id, it can be a `Mage_Core_Model_Store` object, too, so you can use `Mage::app()->getStore()` inline to speed things up.

Comment: And you can use it to fetch multiple attributes: @param int|string|array $attribute atrribute's ids or codes

(in 1.7)

Comment: I like this approach, very neat. I've up-voted. I'll accept if nobody comes up with an answer to the URL.

Comment: Can this still be used without a product ID? If I only have a SKU, am I forced to load the model?

Comment: No. product ID is required parameter.

Comment: Note that in case there are more than a product with the same `url_key` this may not work because magento gonna create a different url rewrite from the url_key

Answer (score 11):

I think it would be beneficial to do this via a collection. If you do not need the complete product information then you could load it via a collection and so only load information you need. The code would be as follows.

```
$product_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', 16)
    ->addUrlRewrite();
$product_collection_url = $product_collection->getFirstItem()->getProductUrl();
```

Note: the `addUrlRewrite` so that you can get the product url later, this can also take a category id as a parameter, without this the url would not contain the category.

You are still end up calling the `getProductUrl()` which ends up using `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Url`, but this only needs the id, request_path and the url key so it should work without the full product.

Comment: This works good!

Comment: It would seem that $Product->getProductUrl() should be all you need. The "addUrlRewrite()" addition makes the difference - thanks for providing that example.

Answer (score 5):

I guess the most efficent way to get a products rewritten URL *(w/o loading product)* is to look directly on URL rewrite talbe.

```
# returns string "product-url.html"
$productUrl = Mage::getResourceModel('core/url_rewrite')
    ->getRequestPathByIdPath('product/' . $productId, $storeId);
```

To get full category path, use

```
# returns string "full/category/path/product-url.html"
$productUrl = Mage::getResourceModel('core/url_rewrite')
    ->getRequestPathByIdPath('product/' . $productId . '/' . $categoryId, $storeId);
```

---

**Edit:** tested for "url_key", for other attributes `getAttributeRawValue` should fit.

1. `getRequestPathByIdPath`

   - Total Incl. Wall Time (microsec):    8,323 microsecs
   - Total Incl. CPU (microsecs): 8,038 microsecs
   - Total Incl. MemUse (bytes):  273,872 bytes
   - Total Incl. PeakMemUse (bytes):  213,488 bytes
   - Number of Function Calls:    372
2. `getAttributeRawValue`

   - Total Incl. Wall Time (microsec): 51,213 microsecs
   - Total Incl. CPU (microsecs):  50,390 microsecs
   - Total Incl. MemUse (bytes):   1,223,520 bytes
   - Total Incl. PeakMemUse (bytes):   1,168,496 bytes
   - Number of Function Calls: 2,233
3. `load(productId)`

   - Total Incl. Wall Time (microsec):    605,649 microsecs
   - Total Incl. CPU (microsecs): 598,820 microsecs
   - Total Incl. MemUse (bytes):  5,370,848 bytes
   - Total Incl. PeakMemUse (bytes):  5,314,384 bytes
   - Number of Function Calls:    27,774

Answer (score 3):

I found this question, wondering the same. And just in case someone else needs this sometime, I'll post my own findings here.

I found two methods of getting the product URL without loading the complete product. Since I was working on a slow server, I needed to find the fastest loading method.

**The first method:**

The first get's a product collection based on the product ID:

```
$_item = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('product_url')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $productId)
    ->addUrlRewrite()
    ->load();

foreach($_item as $product){
    echo $product->getProductUrl();
}

// returns string "http://www.your-domain.com/[category]/[product_url]"
```

**The second method:**

The second method, using Kalpesh Metha's method, would be this code:

```
Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product')
      ->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'url_key', Mage::app()->getStore());

// returns string "product-url-like-this"
```

For this method, you can either use `'url_key'` or `'url_path'`. I have not found out the difference though.

**The difference between the methods:**

The first method takes slightly more time (about 15% time extra). The second method however, only returns the final part of the URL. This means that if the shop uses the category in the URL, it won't work, since that part isn't shown. This was the case in the shop I was working on.