# how to get product url in custom grid?

Tags: product-attribute, grid

I have created a grid and in one of the columns I want to show the full path of the product url that we can go to the product currently i did this in grid.php:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $store = $this->_getStore();

       $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()

            ->addAttributeToSelect('url_key');
//some code
}
```

and for the index I used it :

```
   protected function _prepareColumns()
    {


     $this->addColumn('link',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('link'),
                'index'=>'url_key'
        )); 
//somecode
}
```

is there any clean way so that instead of just the url key i will have the whole url in there?
I want it to be `www.domain.com/urlkey` rather than just the url key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regarding to [David Manners](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10200/efficient-get-product-url-from-id)

renderer would be like this:

```
class Ailin_Orders_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_LinkRender
extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {     
      $product_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $row["entity_id"])
        ->addUrlRewrite();
        $product_collection_url = $product_collection->getFirstItem()->getProductUrl(); 
       return $product_collection_url;
    }
}
```

and then in the _prepareColumns we call it:

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
       $this->addColumn('link',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('link'),
                 'renderer'  => 'ailin_orders/adminhtml_sales_linkrender'
        )); 
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this in your `Grid.php`

```
$this->addColumn('link', array(
                'header'        => $this->__('Product Url'),
                'index'         => 'url_key',
                'type'          => 'text',
                'sortable'  => false,
                'filter'    => false,
                'width' => "20px",
                'renderer'  => 'your_block/adminhtml_catalog_product_grid_renderer_link',
            ));
```

Now create a file `Link.php` in `Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Grid/Renderer/`

```
<?php
class  Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Grid_Renderer_Link
extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{


    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {

        $storeId = (int) Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
        $url = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($row["entity_id"])->getProductUrl();
       return "<a href='$url' target='blank'>URL</a>";
    }

}
```

I haven't tested, but should work.

Comment: Should work, but you'll have a full product load for every single row, which will be very slow. Better prepare the collection with all attributes you need and use `$row` directly, which is the product model

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea because I already have my collectoin in prepareCollection function, this will cause heavy load

Answer (score 1):

You could use an addtional column of the type `action` to show a link:

```
     $this->addColumn('link',
        array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('link'),
            'type'      => 'action',
            'getter'     => 'getId',
            'actions'   => array(
                array(
                    'caption' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('link'),
                    'url'     => Mage::getBaseUrl() . '$url_key',
                )
            ),
    ));
```

`'$url_key'` will be replaced with the value of the `url_key` column.

Comment: have tried but it not works..

Comment: how $url_key can come from that

Comment: Magic. It is weird syntax but Magento does it the same way in the core. You must load the `url_key` attribute in the collection, of course. It might also be necessary to include it as additional column, I did not test it.

Comment: I don't think so, we have index->url_key which will assign the keys I cannot even assign it to $url_key